# What are the strengths of Lua over CSharpCodeProvider in C# for dynamic code execution?

Tags: c#, lua

In my scenario I want to interpret a script file and execute methods from assemblies.  What advantages would Lua offer me?  If you have used both Lua and the CSharpCodeProvider please contrast your experience with both.

Comment: Could you edit your question to ask people to compare and contrast the APIs, not just the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of C# is that it is compiled and JITted (although LUA has experimental code down those routes).

The main advantage of LUA is that it doesn't need to be compiled. It runs slower, but it has a better bootstrap time. It also has a lower amount of bootstrap code (e.g. you don't need to type using System; ... namespace MyNs { ... class MyClass { ... and so on).

In the end the reign of LUA in the scripting world is supreme: but it can't stand up to what C# can do in the performance world, and visa-versa.

Comment: Performance of scripts is often irrelevant.  Can you comment on other aspects?

Comment: Other aspects? I use scripting where scripting is appropriate and compiled where compiled is appropriate. Using a scripting language to create a rich enterprise CRM is a poor idea IMHO. Using C# to create a game script is just as pointless. Use the correct tool for the correct job: neither is better

Comment: Oh, also, CSharpCodeProvider is superior when you are writing programs using a program. Lua is superior when you need to allow the user to change functionality. CSharpCodeProvider is better (if used for scripting) for very advanced end users, Lua is better for advanced users.

Comment: Oh! As well, Lua is more contained. With C# you *could* by mistake allow a script to more than it should be allowed to. Lua's only interface to the outside world is what you give it. That said, C# is more flexible for script writers. My honest opinion is give the user the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out IronPython?  It is very similar to Lua, but is a native CLR language.